# Why should we use rollback in sql explicitly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3

I have one misunderstanding about transactions and how they work. Suppose we wrapped some SQL operator within a transaction like the following:

```
BEGIN;
   insert into tbl (name, val) VALUES('John', 'Doe');
   insert into tbl (name, val) VALUES('John', 'Doee');
COMMIT;
```

If something goes wrong the transaction will automatically be rolled back. Taking that into account I can't get when should we use ROLLBACK explicitly? Could you get an example when it's necessary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In PostgreSQL the transaction is *not* automatically rolled back on error.

It is set to the aborted state, where further commands will fail with an error until you roll the transaction back.

Observe:

```
regress=> BEGIN;
BEGIN
regress=> LOCK TABLE nosuchtable;
ERROR:  relation "nosuchtable" does not exist
regress=> SELECT 1;
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
regress=> ROLLBACK;
ROLLBACK
```

This is important, because it prevents you from accidentally executing half a transaction. Imagine if PostgreSQL automatically rolled back, allowing new implicit transactions to occur, and you tried to run the following sequence of statements:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO archive_table SELECT * FROM current_tabble;
DELETE FROM current_table;
COMMIT;
```

PostgreSQL will abort the transaction when it sees the typo `current_tabble`. So the `DELETE` will never happen - all statements get ignored after the error, and the `COMMIT` is treated as a `ROLLBACK` for an aborted transaction:

```
regress=> BEGIN;
BEGIN
regress=> SELECT typo;
ERROR:  column "typo" does not exist
regress=> COMMIT;
ROLLBACK
```

If it instead automatically rolled the transaction back, it'd be like you ran:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO archive_table SELECT * FROM current_tabble;
ROLLBACK; -- automatic
BEGIN; -- automatic
DELETE FROM current_table;
COMMIT; -- automatic
```

... which, needless to say, would probably make you quite upset.

Comment: Why is the last commit in your the last example automatic?

Comment: @St.Antario If there's no explicit `BEGIN`, PostgreSQL runs statements in autocommit mode.

Comment: One more question. I didn't understand you the first example. What does reggress mean?

Comment: @St.Antario That's the database name I was connected to, from my `psql` prompt. Think `postgres=# `

Answer (score 1):

Other uses for explicit `ROLLBACK` are manual modification and test cases:

- Do some changes to the data (`UPDATE`, `DELETE` ...).
- Run `SELECT` statements to check results of data modification.
- Do `ROLLBACK` if results are not as expected.

In Postgres DB you can do this even with DDL statements (`CREATE TABLE`, ...)